# Symfony 2 DQL query to find unstranslated records

Tags: mysql, symfony, translation, dql

I have to find unstranled records of one of my entity, let's call it `Product`.

I have settled one `Product` entity with all the translatable attributes and the locale (title/text/locale). 
I also have settled one `ProductParent` entity with all the attributes that don't need translation (image).
`ProductParent` is linked to `Product` through a `ManyToOne` relation (`Product` being the owner of the relation).

Product looks like :
`id | title | text | parent_id | locale`

ProductParent looks like :
`id | image`

What I need now is being able to fetch which records in `Product` have not been translated into a given locale ('es'), 'en' being the 'default' locale.
So I need to find all the records which only have a locale = en.

I've started a DQL query but it's not working at all and it's really not my "cup of tea".

```
SELECT a 
FROM ProductParent a
LEFT JOIN Product b
ON a.id = b.parent_id
WHERE b.locale
IN ("en", "es")
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT * < 2
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this query works for me :

```
public function findUnstranslated($default, $locale)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.parent', 'parent')
        ->where('p.locale IN (:locale)')
        ->setParameter('locale', [$default, $locale])
        ->groupBy('parent.id')
        ->having('COUNT(parent.id) < 2')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
public function findUnstranslated($default) {

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.parent_id', 'parent')
        ->where('p.locale = :locale')
        ->setParameter('locale', $default)
        ->groupBy('parent.id')
        ->having('COUNT(parent.id) < 2')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, quite helping, please see my answer below.

Comment: Just edited. Tell me if you have the result(s) expected.

Comment: Nope, it just returns all my 'default locale' records.

Comment: You said "But I only need the records in 'en' ($defaul there)".

Comment: Yes haha, but the point first is to get unstralated records of the default locale. :) with your solution, I get all records of the default (translated and untranslated).

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could do smth like this:

```
... WHERE b.locale = 'en' AND b.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `blah-blah` WHERE locale = "es")
```

Comment: This is working, but in terms of performances, I'm not sure this is the best. But thanks !

Comment: Yes, it's not so good if we are talking about performance, but if I remember - using HAVING, and as I see, it's even HAVING with COUNT, - is more expensive.